# Css grid header not displaying right on Chrome and Opera but works on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid

First time I'm trying to make a website layout using grid and it works just fine on Firefox. Header takes all the desired space but on Chrome and Opera it clumps with all its content into more less 1/3 of the width leaving the rest empty. Everything else besides the header works fine on every browser, including the mobile layout.
All my browsers are up to date.

I don't know how to approach the issue.

```
div.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
grid-template-areas: 
"site-header site-header site-header"
"site-nav content sidebar";
grid-gap: 0;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;}

.site-header {
grid-area: site-header;
height: 250px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
text-align: center;
display: table;
background-color: green;}
```

Comment: Can you show your relevant [mcve] HTML and CSS in order that we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with `display: table` inside a Grid. In your situation, Chrome computes the `width` to `0`.

If you explicitly set the `width` property it appears to work.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/vdxkhzwj/2/)

```css
div.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "site-header site-header site-header" "site-nav content sidebar";
  grid-gap: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.site-header {
  grid-area: site-header;
  height: 250px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="site-header"></header>
</div>
```

Comment: That indeed solved the problem. Works on all the browsers now. Thank you so much.